# Different images in tooltips in Highcharts diagrams

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I am looking for a sample of Javascript code to visualise pictures in a tooltip of a pie chart from Highcharts.

I would like to see different pictures according to the sectors I am navigating on...

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could enable [HTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) in the tooltip, and set the HTML content with a [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).

```
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<img src="/your/image/path/' + this.series.name + '.png" />' + '<b>' + this.point.y + '</b>';
            }
        }
```

In this case, the image being loaded is based on on each series name. If your series were named Apples, Oranges, and Bananas, you just need to make apples.png, oranges.png, and bananas.png and set the path in that img tag appropriately.